# TFS reporting issue. Reportable fields

Tags: tfs, reporting

I have a question about TFS reporting. Here is the situation.  I want to include a field called "release notes" in some reports.  This field is an HTML filed and can not be set to reportable as far as I know.

I could copy the info from the HTML field to a string field.  Strings are reportable.  However they are only 256 chars.

So, given these conditions how would I get the data in the "relase notes" HTML field to finally be reportable.

I've been looking everywhere and can't find any good solutions.

Thanks for your kind attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reportable=detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194980.aspx#Reporting)  to let them show up in the warehouse. They will not be in the cube, but you can at least report on them.

Comment: Huh, no, can't set the "Reportable" attribute for Html field types.